# iOS 9.0 Xcode 8.3.3 MfiBtPrinterConnection.h streming bluetooth maxLength Zebra ZQ520

Tags: ios, xcode, bluetooth, zebra-printers

I'm using the Zebra printer sdk in particular I have a Zebra ZQ520.
I'm trying to send a string (in the proprietary language called "zpl") to the printer from my project in Xcode (Object-C).

Before this stage, I convert a * .pdf into a * .grf image I take the entire string and firing the printer. So far it has always worked, but if I take a somewhat more complex pdf, I get this error back.

> ERROR - /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/ExternalAccessory/ExternalAccessory-353.50.4/EAOutputStream.m:-[EAOutputStream
>   write: maxLength:] - 283 failed to write because stream does not have
>   space available

I checked that the connection I create comes from the MfiBtPrinterConnection.h class and with the instance, I create I can only touch two values ​​with these methods setTimeToWaitAfterWriteInMilliseconds and setTimeToWaitAfterReadInMilliseconds. The SDK manual tells you to try to increase the time in case of writing problems. I tried up to 30 seconds but nothing. Unfortunately I do not have access to the sources.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?

Comment: yes, i fixed it many months ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this error today, although my content is different hopefully it will help you. I had to put my .write command on a background thread.

```
             var error:NSError?
             DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                MfiBtPrinterConnection?.write(data, withOffset: 0, andWithLength: data.count - 1, error: &error)
                if error != nil {
                print("Error executing data writing \(String(describing: error))")
             }
```

Now my data prints like it should.